# Insertion of same elements in Red-Black Tree?

Tags: database, tree

How Red Black Tree will formed if we insert same elements, for example inserting 8,8,8,8,8,8,8  .

Answer (score 1):

If you insert `8,8,8,8,8,8,8` it will be displayed something like below,
because Red-Black Tree follows these properties:
**A red-black tree is a balanced binary search tree with the following properties:**

- Every node is colored red or black.
- Every leaf is a NIL node, and is colored black.
- If a node is red,
  then both its children are black.
- Every simple path from a node to a
  descendant leaf contains the same number of black nodes.

[image: Red black tree]